# UI-Less authentication with PRT

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to authenticate the logged-on user with my cloud application.
I've a rich application on the end-point (C++ or C#).
I've a cloud application (not necessarily HTTP protocol), running on Linux (I can change that, if I need Windows to support this scenario).

Assuming the Windows is AzureAD joined (or registered - not sure yet the difference, I'm at the beginning of the learning curve), and the user performed logged in with its Azure credentials.

I would like to get the user identity (domain, user name, SID, etc.) on my server application, in a way that is seamless (i.e. UI-less) to the user. It should be like accessing a shared resource on the local network (e.g. NAS).

What do I need to implement on the client? What do I need to implement on the server? Which API should I use? Which document I should read? where do I start?